# Why can't I merge my PDFs built from image strings?

Tags: php, pdf

Let's say I have an array of objects `$shippingDetails`, where each `shippingDetail` has a property `image_string`.

I am converting each image_string into a PDF using `pdf_decode` and `file_put_contents`. I would like to merge the PDFs together.

Why is my code below not working?:

```
    $fileArray = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach($shippingDetails as $shippingDetail) {

        $pdf_decoded = base64_decode ($shippingDetail['image_string']);
        $tempName = 'temp' . $i++ . '.pdf';
        file_put_contents($tempName, $pdf_decoded);

        $fileArray[] = $tempName;
    }

    $dataDir = 'save_path/';
    $outputName = $dataDir . 'shippingLabel.pdf';

    $cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outputName ";

    //Add each pdf file to the end of the command
    foreach($fileArray as $file) {
        $cmd .= $file." ";
    }
    $result = shell_exec($cmd);
```

All I'm getting as output is the last PDF.

Comment: If you `var_log($cmd)` do you get more than one file path?

Comment: Yes: `gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=save_path/shippingLabel.pdf temp0.pdf temp1.pdf`

Comment: seems like it might be a unix command issue. You may get a response faster posting in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Reposted on Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266859/why-cant-i-merge-my-pdfs-built-from-image-strings). This question is ok for either site, but please [pick one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and delete the other.

Comment: Alright, I deleted it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that this wasn't working because I didn't have GhostScript installed on my server.

Before I realized that, I ended up using [libmergepdf by hanneskod](https://github.com/hanneskod/libmergepdf) and it worked perfectly, if anyone stumbles upon this in the future.